# Jenkins & Sonarqube - Illegal Reflect

Tags: jenkins, msbuild, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

I try to analyse a .net project with jenkins & sonarqube.
When I try to analyze the project localy on my workstation without jenkins the analysis works and the results are uploaded and displayed in sonarqube.
When I use jenkins in combination with sonar msbuild and execute the very same cmd I get the error message

```
: WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: WARNING: Illegal reflective access by net.sf.cglib.core.ReflectUtils$1 (file:/C:/Users/xyz/.sonar/cache/132aaa5c3a6da2c09af83d327b1fc182/sonar-javascript-plugin-4.1.0.6085.jar) to method java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(java.lang.String,byte[],int,int,java.security.ProtectionDomain)
WARNING: WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of net.sf.cglib.core.ReflectUtils$1
WARNING: WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
WARNING: WARN: Analyzer working directory does not exist: 'D:\Jenkins\workspace\GLB\.sonarqube\out\2\output-cs'. Analyzer results won't be loaded from this directory.
```

As far as I could see this is the only difference between the local working version vs. the not working version via jenkins.

I already invested a lot of time in investigating and research but did not find a solution for that.

kind regards

Answer (score 0):

It's not your fault.

Please check following reply on GitHub - https://github.com/SonarSource/SonarJS/issues/1110

> Hello,
>   as you note, this is just a warning and it can be safely ignored. We cannot fix this warning easily, because it's a dependency of our parser which would need fixing. However we started migration to another parser in 5.0 and gradually we will migrate all rules to the new parser. This will eventually allow to drop dependency on sslr and fix the warning

Answer (score 0):

this issue encountered because of space issue on the device.
check where this service running,

- df -h
  if there is space issue exist,
- remove unused files.